# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1. How to fix this

Tags: python, setup.py, error-code, polyglot

How do I fix this. I cannot find any directory with "Temp\pip-install-7utykvpt\polyglot"

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install polyglot
Collecting polyglot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/98/e24e2489114c5112b083714277204d92d372f5bbe00d5507acf40370edb9/polyglot-16.7.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7utykvpt\polyglot\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        readme = readme_file.read()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4941: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7utykvpt\polyglot\
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory is temporary, as it says in the name. pip will destroy it when it finishes running if it failed or succeeded.

Your error is pretty clear, it's telling you that while reading the readme file it found a unicode character it doesn't know how to decode.

This looks like it's a known issue, https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/127, https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/93, https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/91. A variety of solutions are provided in the linked issues.